# Comparing smallest user input for C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I tried to find the smallest number within 3 inputs. Here is my codes :

```
int main ()
{
     double x = 4.0;
     double y = 5.0;
     double z = 3.0;
     smallest(x,y,z);
     cout << smallest << endl;
     system("PAUSE");

}

double smallest(double x, double y, double z)
{
     double smallest;

     if ((x < y)||(x< z)) {
        smallest = x;
     } else if ((y < z)||(y < x)) {
        smallest = y;
     } else {
        smallest = z;
     }
     return smallest;

}
```

However, I keep getting error. It stated that my smallest method in main method with undeclared identifier. This works when using eclipse but not visual studio. Can somebody explain to me why?

Thanks in advance.

**Updated portion.**

So I tried to do validation for this program. I want to ensure users only enter number and here are my codes :

```
    double x, y, z;
bool correct_input = false;
do{
    cout << "Enter first integer : " ;
    cin >> x;
    if(isdigit(x)){
        correct_input = true;
    }
}while(!correct_input);
do{
    cout << "Enter second integer : ";
    cin >> y;
    if(isdigit(y)){
        correct_input = true;
    }
}while(!correct_input);
do{
    cout << "Enter third integer : ";
    cin >> z;
    if(isdigit(z)){
        correct_input = true;
    }
}while(!correct_input);

cout << "Smallest integer is : " << smallest(x,y,z) << endl;
system("PAUSE");
```

When I entered alphabet or whatever except numbers, I get debug assertion failed. It does not prompt until user enter correct input. Can somebody help?

Comment: you need to forward declare smallest() ...

Comment: What does that means?

Comment: @Rauryn Search for `forward declaration c++`.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, if you wish to use `smallest()` before it's defined, you need to prototype it. Add the following before `main()`:

```
double smallest(double x, double y, double z);
```

Also, you are ignoring the return value of `smallest()`. Change

```
smallest(x,y,z);
cout << smallest << endl;
```

to

```
double smallest_val = smallest(x,y,z);
cout << smallest_val << endl;
```

Comment: It fixed after I added the line before main. So in C++ whatever method we needed, we need to declare it before the main?

Comment: This will not correct, what he did about that is correct, he will get just warning

Comment: Yes, if `smallest()` is defined before `main()`, it will compile.  Though, it appears good practice to do a function prototype before `main()`, and declare the function implementation after `main()`.  See function prototyping: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype

Answer (score 5):

This isn't the question you asked but your function is bugged because you confused `||` and `&&`.

Your function should be

```
double smallest(double x, double y, double z)
{
    double smallest;

    if (x < y && x < z)
        smallest = x;
    else if (y < z && y < x)
        smallest = y;
    else
        smallest = z;
    return smallest;
}
```

`x` is the smallest number if it is less `y` **and** it is less than `z`.

**update**

First thing to say is that if you want *integers* then you should be using `int` not `double`.

Second thing, `isdigit` doesn't do what you think it does. You've actually set yourself a very difficult problem. Here's one way to do it

```
#include <string> // for string class

bool correct_input = false;
do
{
    cout << "Enter first integer : " ;
    if (cin >> x)
    {
        correct_input = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // cin is in a error state after a failed read so clear it
        cin.clear();
        // ignore any remaining input to the end of the line
        string garbage;
        getline(cin, garbage);
    }
}
while(!correct_input);
```

But this doesn't work perfectly. For instance if you enter abc then your program will ask for more input, but if you enter 123abc, then you will get the integer 123 even though 123abc is not a valid number.

If you really want to do this properly (and it is hard) then you must read in a string, check if the string could be converted to a number, if it can then do the conversion, if it can't then ask for more input.

Comment: But the question asks for double. Is it fine that I keep the double and use your code?

Comment: @rauryn, yes but then obviously you should change your messages to "Enter first number ..."

Comment: But yours only check for the first input. It does not work with second n third inputs

Comment: @Rauryn I think your code is bugged, you need to add `correct_input = false;` before each loop.

Comment: Well then you should figure out what's wrong. I don't think there's any reason my code won't work for any many inputs as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line above your main ;).

```
double smallest(double x, double y, double z);
```

You need to declare any function you make. This is called making a function header.

Comment: Function prototype or function declaration are the usual terms I think.

Comment: Oh by the way I was thinking of to ensure user only enters digit. I will update my code later and please help me check

Comment: @JesseMoreland Can you help me check with my updated portion?

Comment: Rauryn, what you're trying to do is store a letter in a double. Doubles only accept numbers If i'm not mistaken.

Comment: Is this an assignment for a class? If so I don't think you're quite ready to check if it is a digit or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare you function so that the compiler can recognize it.
Put its prototype above main function as this:

```
double smallest(double, double, double);
int main()
{
//Staff
}
```

Comment: Thanks thanks. So far I understand that for whatever methods in C++, we need to declare it before the main method. Is it correct?

Comment: @Rauryn, nearly, you need to declare it before you *use* it, wherever that is.

Comment: Where's it? Can you update in your comment? It keeps prompting enter first integer

Comment: "correct_input==false" is replaced by "!correct_input", and a direct call of "smallest(x,y,z)" because there is no need to use an intermediate variable :)

Comment: But it doesn't prompt for user input. It just terminate the program when it detects wrong input

Comment: What you did is correct only one time you used "correct_input=false" which was not correct but I meant that the use of "!correct_input" is more professional

Answer (score 0):

There are two problem, here, one related to how to get the smallest, and the other related to ho get correct input.

For the first problem, let me propose a recursive approach:

```
// this is trivial
double smallest(double x, double y)
{ return (x<y)? x: y; }

// the smalles of three is the smallest between the smallest of two and the third
double smallest(double x, double y, double z)
{ return smallest(smallest(x,y),z); }
```

For the second problem, you have the same problem for each of the variables, so let's make a function for it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

double read(std::istream& s, std::ostream& o, const std::string& message)
{
    for(;;) //stay here until kiked out
    {
        double d=0.; //just a safe value - no particular meaning

        o << message << std::endl; // prompt the request
        bool good(s >> d); //read a double and keep the state
        if(!good) s.clear(); //if we failed to read, clean the stream state

        //in any case, discard everything unread until the return.
        s.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 

        if(good) return d; //if reading succeeded, return.
        //overwise loop back
    }
}
```

This is based on the fact the `std::cin` have a state that is set to "bad" is the input cannot be read in the given variable.

We just read, and, if it fails, redo again and again. 
But fist we have to clear the state, so thet the input can be unlocked.
Independently og good an bad reading, we have then to discard everuthing "extra" that can be typed in the line (think to `123asdf`: we successfully read `123`, but we have to discard `abc`)
The the reading was successful we just return it, otherwise we loop over and over until we get it.

The program itself, at this point will reduce to:

```
int main()
{
    double x = read(std::cin, std::cout, "Enter first value");
    double y = read(std::cin, std::cout, "Enter second value");
    double z = read(std::cin, std::cout, "Enter third value");

    std::cout << "the smallest numer is: " << smallest(x,y,z) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

that can run this way:

```
Enter first value
7
Enter second value
5.2yyyy
Enter third value
sf3
Enter third value
455
the smallest numer is: 5.2
```

---

A more advanced technique can be transform the function into a manipulator class, like this:

```
class read_value
{
public:
    read_value(double& d, const std::string& prompt_, std::ostream& out_ = std::cout)
        :z(d), prompt(prompt_), outstream(out_)
    {}

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, const read_value& a)
    { 
        for(;;)
        {
            a.outstream << a.prompt << std::endl; // prompt the request
            bool good(s >> a.z); //read a double and keep the state
            if(!good) s.clear(); //if we failed to read, cleanr the stream state

            //in any case, discard everything unread until the return.
            s.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 

            if(good) return s; //if reading succeeded, return.
            //overwise loop back
        }
    }

private:
    double& z;
    std::string prompt;
    std::ostream& outstream;
};
```

letting the program a more idiomatic form:

```
int main()
{
    double x,y,z;

    std::cin >> 
        read_value(x,"Enter first value") >>
        read_value(y,"Enter second value") >>
        read_value(z,"Enter third value");

    std::cout << "the smallest numer is: " << smallest(x,y,z) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Another point can be the fact the user can loop forever by never typing a good sequence.

We can fix a maximum attempt limit introducing a counter in the for loop, and setting the input to "failed" if the loop terminates without returning:

```
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, const read_value& a)
{
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
       ... //same as before
    }
    return s; //s will be returned in failed state
}
```

And then checking in the main program:

```
int main()
{
    double x,y,z;

    std::cin >> 
        read_value(x,"Enter first value") >>
        read_value(y,"Enter second value") >>
        read_value(z,"Enter third value");

    if(!std::cin) 
    { 
       std::cout << "bad input." << std::endl;
       return -1; //report as "program failed"
    }

    std::cout << "the smallest numer is: " << smallest(x,y,z) << std::endl;
    return 0; //succeeded
}
```

.

Comment: Is it C++ language? Because I am a novice and I hvn't seen any std:: before

Comment: @Rauryn: Yes, it is. And if you never saw it, you'd better to reconsider what you are studying: the `std` namespace was introduced in 1999, when C++ became an ISO standard. Unfortunately many old books and outdated internet sites and tutorial are around!